# What is the English equivalent of "Ich rieche dich"?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage, german-to-english

My German boyfriend uses the expression "Ich rieche dich". I know that the English translation is "I can smell you", but it doesn't sound very flattering. What would the English equivalent be or isn't there one?

Comment: The German phrase given is neither common (I never heard it) nor necessarily more flattering. A more poetical variant could sound somewhat like "Dein Duft umgibt mich..."

Comment: If he says that while you are standing three meters apart, it is indeed not flattering. If he says it while you are intimate, that is a completely different matter.

Comment: Flatly, he can sense "you" by his olfactory senses - but we couldn't say whether it's your individual scent, your perfume or your BO. Per se, it's neutral, context is the key.

Comment: In The Simpsons s08e07, side character Nelson Muntz uses "Ich riech' dich später." / "Smell you later" instead of saying "See you later" / "Ich seh' dich später.". Depending on your bf's inclinations and the context which you neglected to describe, that might be a pop cultural reference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it' not a question about German language. It is about English. You should ask it in http://english.stackexchange.com. The meaning of “Ich rieche dich” seems to be clear, so this is not a question about the German phrase. You are looking for a translation in a foreign language (other than German), but this is off-topic in German-SE.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - I read this question as "I know the literal translation is X, but is there a secondary meaning of the German original which I don't get?". Perhaps OP could clarify or edit the question...?

Comment: There's the idiomatic expression "jemanden nicht riechen können" = to dislike somebody, to have a bad chemistry with somebody. The "nicht können" is important. Maybe that's what you heard? I've never heard the expression "Ich rieche dich". Maybe it's very particular to your boyfriend... If you could give some context, it would help tremendously.

Comment: And if the context is in a more or less intimate situation, with his nose close to you, the meaning is obviously "I like how you smell" etc. How to find a good English expression for that is indeed off-topic here.

Comment: @Stephie: I agree, (that's why I've written an answer), but the OP doesn't ask for the meaning of the German phrase. He or she explicitly asks for a translation in English (“*What would the English equivalent be*”). And this is explicitly off-topic. Quote from help-center: “*Translations requests from German should be restricted to cases where a profound knowledge of German is needed for understanding a phrase or an idiom.*”

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - that's *exactly* what I'm referring to in my comment... (Or rather, a request whether with profund knowledge of German another meaning appears.)

Comment: @c.p. and close voters agreeing with his reason: "context is missing" is not a reason for marking something as off-topic. That's what the "unclear what you're asking" reason is for.

Comment: @chirlu Exactly. Additionally, like Stephie observed, there is a good chance that the OP asked for an English translation to understand the German term better, which would be on-topic. Once more we confront a new, probably unexperienced user with closing her question without even awaiting her reaction to all these comments. What's German for "you are welcome"?

Comment: Guys, you *do* realize that there is always only *one* reason given even if *multiple* vote-types contributed to the five required votes? I really hope that the new user will edit the question and we can either re-open or confirm that the votes were justified.

Comment: @Stephie: Yes, but I saw the distribution of close votes when I cast my own (the fifth). :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a German native speaker, English is a foreign language to me. I would have thought “*Ich rieche dich*” would translate to “*I (can) smell you*”. But obviously you are not happy with it. I just can compare the phrase with others:

**Ich sehe dich**
Light from a light source is reflected by your body. Some of this reflected light reaches my eyes, where it is registered. My brain calculates a picture of your body from the signals that the eyes sent to it.
I would translate it as “*I (can) see you*”.

**Ich höre dich**
You are emitting sound waves (they can be produced because you are singing or talking, but also because you are walking, typing or something else). Some of those waves reach my ears, and from this point it is very similar to seeing.
I would translate it as “*I (can) hear you*”.

**Ich rieche dich**
Your body is emitting chemical substances, that are gases or that can easily be vaporized and so are solved in air. Some of this air with those substances reaches my nose. There are sensors, that are able to register many of this substances. This sensors send signals to the brain, and the brain forms the olfactory sensation.
I would translate it as “*I (can) smell you*”.

I think, your point is, that you think to say “Ich rieche dich” is not flattering. But this phrase is - without any additional context - neutral. If one wants to say, that you are smelling bad, he would say “du stinkst” or “du riechst schlecht”. Less clear, also meaning smelling bad is “du riechst”.

If you are smelling good, he could say “du riechst gut” or “Ich mag deinen Geruch”.

Many people fear that the natural odor of their body might smell bad. But this is not true. Fresh sweat doesn't smell bad, and your body produces substances that really can smell good (did you ever hold your nose very close to a babies head and smell how good its hair smells?) It takes some hours until bacteria can transform substances on your skin that don't smell into substances that smell bad. Then you are stinking. But as said: This needs lots of hours.

A person, that showers daily in the morning doesn't smell bad until the evening. He/she smells, but just like a normal human, which is not bad.

If your boyfriend has fallen in love with you, he will recognize you natural smell and the best thing he could smell.

Comment: For spoken language, you might also consider the sortened form "Ich (be-)rieche dich"... There are so many possibilities, I really hope OP comes back to clarify and add context.